# Type Mismatch for Index Key personID Expected: S Actual B DynamoDB Save Error in Java

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I  using DynamoDB mapper and I have the following Item.class. The values are encrypted using a KMS key.

```
public class Item {
private String id
private String personID;

@DynamoDBHashKey
@DynamoDBGeneratedUuid(DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.CREATE)
public String getId(){
    return id;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute
@DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "personID-index")
public String getPersonID() {
    return personID;
}
};
```

When I try to save an Item it gives me the following error

```
AmazonDynamoDBException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Type mismatch for Index Key personID Expected: S Actual: B IndexName: personID-index
```

Eventhough the error says I am sending it as B, according to my code it is a string value which is S.

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.DataTypes.html S - String and B is Binary. I cannot see where my personID get converted to a binary value.

Any help regarding getting rid of the error is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the PersonID is encrypted using KMS key. You can specifically say that do not sign or encrypt the attribute using `@DoNotTouch` annotation.

```
public class Item {
private String id
private String personID;

@DynamoDBHashKey
@DynamoDBGeneratedUuid(DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.CREATE)
public String getId(){
    return id;
}

@DoNotTouch
@DynamoDBAttribute
@DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "personID-index")
public String getPersonID() {
    return personID;
}
};
```

If you want the key encrypted you can also server side encryption as DynamoDB now supports server side encryption at Rest. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/02/amazon-dynamodb-now-supports-server-side-encryption-at-rest/